# How can I pass data between a statefulwidget children to his parent in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want pass the boolean **_isSwitched** from **SetAvailableSwitch class** to **AvailableScreen class**

But actually I can't retrieve the boolean in AvailableScreen class. And as you can see SetAvailableSwitch class is in the `Widget build` of AvailableScreen class so I don't know how to do that.

**AvailableScreen class :**

```
class AvailableScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const AvailableScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AvailableScreenState();
}

class _AvailableScreenState extends State<AvailableScreen>
{

  void _sendAvailability(BuildContext context)
  {
    PhpPost().sendAvailability();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SetAvailableSwitch(),
              const AvailableSelectGame(),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                    _sendAvailability(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text("OK"))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

**SetAvailableSwitch class :**

```
class SetAvailableSwitch extends StatefulWidget {

  const SetAvailableSwitch({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SetAvailableSwitchState createState() => _SetAvailableSwitchState();
}

class _SetAvailableSwitchState extends State<SetAvailableSwitch> {

  bool _isSwitched = false;

  void _changeSwitch(bool value)
  {
    setState(() {
      if(_isSwitched) {
        _isSwitched = false;
      }

      else{
        _isSwitched = true;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          Languages.of(context)!.available,
          style: const TextStyle(),
        ),
        Switch(value: _isSwitched, onChanged: (value)
        {
          _changeSwitch(value);
        })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the boolean in the function `void _sendAvailability(BuildContext context)` in **AvailableScreen class**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to add a callback method to `_AvailableScreenState`:

```
class _AvailableScreenState extends State<AvailableScreen> {
  bool _isSwitched = false;

  void setIsSwitched(switched) {
    setState(() {
      _isSwitched = switched;
    });
    print(_isSwitched);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SetAvailableSwitch(setIsSwitched),
```

Which you can call from `SetAvailableSwitch`:

```
class SetAvailableSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(bool) setSwitched;

  const SetAvailableSwitch(this.setSwitched, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SetAvailableSwitchState createState() => _SetAvailableSwitchState();
}

class _SetAvailableSwitchState extends State<SetAvailableSwitch> {
  bool _isSwitched = false;

  void _changeSwitch(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      if (_isSwitched) {
        _isSwitched = false;
      } else {
        _isSwitched = true;
      }
    });
    widget.setSwitched(_isSwitched);
  }
```